# Adding series to highchart and remove loading without creating new chart

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm using Highchart with React.

For the moment I created a starting options:

```js
/**
  * Initial chart options, with "loading" enabled
  */
  const chartOptions = {
    accessibility: {
      enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
      type: "column",
      events: {
        load() {
          const chart = this;
          chart.showLoading(`${LOADING}...`);
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

In that component I call an API that returns some data to use. So, at that moment, I want to remove the "loading" and adding the data.

I solved for the moment with:

```js
const [options, setOptions] = useState(chartOptions);

useEffect(() => {
    if (detail) {
      setOptions({
        ...chartOptions,
        chart: {
          type: "column"
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: detail.map(
            (item) =>
              `${item.data_em.substring(4, 6)}/${item.data_em.substring(0, 4)}`
          )
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: "Alfa",
            color: "#69BC66",
            data: detail.map((item) => item.ricevuti)
          },
          {
            name: "Beta",
            color: "#DC3545",
            data: detail.map((item) => item.mancanti)
          },
        ]
      });
    }
  }, [detail]);


<ChartComponent options={options} />
```

So, setting a new options in local State when data are ready. But I imagine that in this manner I get a different chart.

It works, but is there a better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With using the `highcharts-react-official` wrapper, the chart is recreated on state update only if `immutable` option is enabled. Otherwise, only `chart.update` method is called to apply changes.

Therefore, it is better to apply only the new options. In your case it will be:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (detail) {
    setOptions({
      chart: {
        type: "column"
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: detail.map(
          (item) =>
          `${item.data_em.substring(4, 6)}/${item.data_em.substring(0, 4)}`
        )
      },
      series: [{
          name: "Alfa",
          color: "#69BC66",
          data: detail.map((item) => item.ricevuti)
        },
        {
          name: "Beta",
          color: "#DC3545",
          data: detail.map((item) => item.mancanti)
        },
      ]
    });
  }
}, [detail]);
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-3lvomg?file=/demo.jsx

**Docs:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official#optimal-way-to-update